# "Partitions" of functions, Elementary Question

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the set $S:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid a<f_1(x)+f_2(y)<b\}$, where $f_i$ are real valued continuous functions, and $a$, $b$ real numbers.

I wonder if it is possible to write $S$ as $$S=\bigcup_i (U_i\times V_i)$$
where $$U_i=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid m_i<f_1(x)<M_i\},$$ $$V_i=\{y\in\mathbb{R}\mid m_i'<f_2(y)<M_i'\}$$ for some real numbers $m_i,m_i',M_i,M_i'$?

It is ok if the union is uncountable.

For instance, $S:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid 1<f_1(x)+f_2(y)<10\}$ intuitively can be written as union of 
$\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid 0<f_1(x)<5\}\times\{y\in\mathbb{R}\mid 1<f_2(y)<5\}$and so on.

I.e. all possible tuples of real numbers that sum up to between 1 and 10.

Thanks for any help.

For the bounty, negative answers with counterexample will be awarded, similarly for positive answers with proof/sketch of proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the parallel strip $\Omega:=\{(u,v)| a<u+v<b\}$ in the $(u,v)$-plane. Let $({\bf w}_k)_{k\geq1}$ be a counting of the points with rational coordinates in $\Omega$. Each ${\bf w}_k=(u_k,v_k)$ is the center of an open square $Q_k=I_k\times J_k$ extending to the boundary of $\Omega$. One can prove that the $Q_k$ $(k\geq1)$ constitute a covering of $\Omega$. Now put
$$U_k:=f^{-1}(I_k),\quad V_k:=g^{-1}(J_k)\ .$$
I claim that
$$S=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty U_k\times V_k\ .\tag{1}$$
*Proof.* If $(x,y)\in S$ then $a<f(x)+g(y)<b$, or $(u,v):=\bigl(f(x),g(y)\bigr)\in\Omega$. It follows that there is a $k\geq1$ with $(u,v)\in Q_k=I_k\times J_k$, and this implies $f(x)\in I_k$, $\>g(y)\in J_k$, or $x\in f^{-1}(I_k)=U_k$ and $y\in g^{-1}(J_k)=V_k$. It follows that $(x,y)$ belongs to the union on the right hand side of $(1)$. – I leave the proof of the converse to you.

I think that working with carefully chosen half-open "dyadic" squares $Q_k$ you could even make the union $(1)$  disjoint.